# docker images listed, but not able to delete

Tags: image, docker, jenkins

i am trying to run container using image, but it doesn't detect image locally. whereas the images are listed as shown below. To recover i thought of deleting and re-running. But, i get error in deleting the listed image:
Also, I will like to highlight that i have uninstalled and re-installed docker between first time and 2nd time running the below cmd to start container.

Here is the sequence of steps i have done:

1. Command to run container (which downloaded image when i ran it first)

```
docker container run --name jenkins-docker --rm --detach \
>   --privileged --network jenkins --network-alias docker \
>   --env DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR=/certs \
>   --volume jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client \
>   --volume jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \
>   --volume "$HOME":/home docker:dind
```

2. Uninstalled and re-installed docker
3. Re-run above cmd to start conatiner (got below error)

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers).
See 'docker run --help'.
```

4. list image

```
REPOSITORY            TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
jenkinsci/blueocean   latest              b9a3e09d0e84        22 hours ago        549MB
docker                dind                8489eeb24a26        4 days ago          237MB
```

5. Validate that no container is running

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

6. Deleting images :

```
Error: No such image: b9a3e09d0e84

docker rmi 8489eeb24a26
Error: No such image: 8489eeb24a26
```

Comment: first delete all the exited containers using `docker container prune` and then delete images`docker image prune`. It will delete all the dangling images

Comment: ...or stop Docker, delete all of `/var/lib/docker`, and really start from scratch.

Comment: there were no containers running. i have to clean my setup, thats was the easiest way out. As it was new setup, for me no harm. But, i am hoping there woule be a way out for those having an existing setup.

Answer (score 1):

to force delete all containers, run:

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)
```

to force delete all images, run:

```
docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)
```

to check containers have been deleted, run:

```
docker ps -a
```

to check images have been deleted, run

```
docker images -a
```

you can see errors like following at image deletion time, but you'll see by running `docker images -a` that there is nothing left

```
Error: No such image: 1203fc0eeda3
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue where podman created an image duplicate listed as

```
REPOSITORY   TAG      IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
<none>       <none>   b6513bbf3672   7 minutes ago   116 MB
```

Force deleting with

```
docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)
```

as suggested by fredericrous solved it!